# Get ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException error when try to display data from jtable to the console

Tags: java, arrays, swing, jtable

I got `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` error when I try to display `data` which put into `Vector` from `Jtable` to the `console`

Here the error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3 >= 3
    at java.util.Vector.elementAt(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.table.DefaultTableColumnModel.getColumn(Unknown Source)
at sun.swing.SwingUtilities2.convertColumnIndexToModel(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JTable.convertColumnIndexToModel(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JTable.getValueAt(Unknown Source)
```

Here the code:

```
ResultSet dbresultset = sqlstatement.executeQuery("select * from ***);
ResultSetMetaData rsmetadata = dbresultset.getMetaData();       
int numcols = rsmetadata.getColumnCount();    

if(tglbtnAdd.isSelected() == true)
  {  while (dbresultset.next())
     {    Vector<Object> row = new Vector<Object>(numcols);
      for (int i = 1; i <= numcols; i++)
        {
             row.addElement( dbresultset.getObject(i) );
        }
         defaultmodel2.addRow(row );

          }

ArrayList<String> numdata = new ArrayList<String>();
for(int count = 0; count <= table_1.getRowCount(); count++){
        numdata.add(table_1.getValueAt(count, 3).toString());
    }
System.out.println(numdata);
```

Comment: How do you know there are 3 or more columns?

Comment: That line actually assumes 4 columns. Indexes count starts at 0. I suspect OP is trying to get the value at 3rd column in which case the right call is `table_1.getValueAt(count, 2)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for(int count = 0; count <= table_1.getRowCount(); count++)
```

As mentioned in the comments, indexes range from [0, length). I suspect the problem is that you are using `<=` instead of `<`. It should probably look something like:

```
for(int count = 0; count < table_1.getRowCount(); count++)
```

Comment: To try and get an object from a ResultSet the "idices" actaully start at 1, that's why the OP is using `1` and `<=` in the first loop. You're probably right about the second.

Comment: @peeskillet Fair enough. I shall edit my answer, thanks.